# How does data stored in 64 Architecture

Tags: assembly, memory, data-structures, cpu-architecture

I have two question.

First question:

How does using int instead of long reduce amount of bytes in program? As I understand, we allocate variable, that is, we occupy one address and if we use 64 bit architecture we have 64 bit for every address of memory.

Second question:

How does data which is less than 64 bits is contained in address of memory? It occupies first elements and then writes 0 in other cells?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most 64 bit architectures are still *byte addressed architecture,* i.e. each address refers to 1 byte.  So using a 32 bit datum instead of a 64 bit datum makes it occupy only 4 addresses instead of 8 addresses, saving half the space.

On a 64 bit architecture that is a *word addressed architecture* (i.e. each address refers to one 64 bit word), your first remark is correct.  Using 32 bit variables does not save memory.  As for your second question, zero-extending the datum to fit into 64 bits is a common choice when dealing with 32 bit data on word addressed architectures.